# Add class to python module with boost python

Tags: python, c++, class, boost

I'm trying to add a C++ class to a Python module passed to the `eval()` method.

How can I do this?

For example, when I need to add a simple function, I use this code:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

static int myFunc()
{
    return 3;
}

int main()
{
    auto main_module = boost::python::import("__main__");
    auto main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");
    main_namespace["myFunc"] = boost::python::object(&myFunc);
    auto evalResult = boost::python::eval("myFunc()", main_namespace);
    assert((int)boost::python::extract<int>(evalResult) == 3);
}
```

It works.

How I can add class to `main_module`?

I've tried this:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

struct World
{
    int myFunc()
    {
        return 3;
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
    boost::python::class_<World>("World").def("myFunc", &World::myFunc);
}
 
int main()
{
    auto main_module = boost::python::import("__main__");
    auto main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");

    boost::python::exec("import hello");
    auto evalResult = boost::python::eval("hello.World().myFunc()", main_namespace);
    assert((int)boost::python::extract<int>(evalResult) == 3);
}
```

and get an exception "python::throw_error_already_set()" on `import hello`.
If I remove boost::python::exec("import hello"); line, I get same exception on next line.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Yes, please add the error message. Further, provide a [mcve]. Neither the first nor the second code can be compiled as-is. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Changed the original message. Modified the examples, added an error.